# database output each line on each page

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to put data of each each from my database to each page by modifying it on each page

for example i have on my database with table of :

`id   fname   lname   age
 1     bob     carl   23
 2   michael   jake   25`

now i want each line to show up on each page i want

for example i have
page1.php this must out put the first line like this
`bob     carl     23`

and i have page2.php this must out put the second line like this `michael   jake   25`

and so on.

i have a code like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages";
$results = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $pname = $row["pname"];
        $pimg = $row["pimg"];
        $pstream = $row["pstream"];
    }
}
```

if i echo this out it is gonna output the last line only or with while loop it's gonna output all lines on one page. how can i mark from my code which line should be showing ?

Comment: keep the `while` loop and use line breaks to separate them; seems to be what the question/problem is about.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i don't want to show all lines in one page. i have 2 persons on my database and i want to display them on 2 different pages

Comment: 1 user for each page? your question's/comment's unclear. If so, then you're probably looking for pagination.

Comment: @Fred-ii- dear i know in pagination. i don't mean pagination.

Comment: sorry but I can't heads or tails from what you're asking. Last ditch effort: use sessions.

Comment: You want a pagination of 1 row???

Comment: @Fred-ii- i just want to modify my code to show each person on a page. modified code on each page to display on of them on each page.
i don't want my code to show all of them in one page. i want to tell the server or code which one must be shown here on this page

Comment: @scaisEdge read my last comment please

Comment: Use a `WHERE` clause on your query. Like `WHERE id = 1`

Comment: @JayBlanchard perfect. that is what i meant. please answer the question so i accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show specific data on each page you must modify the query for each page by using additional clauses to filter the data. It all starts with a `WHERE` clause:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE id = 1";
```

The above query will get the data for the matching id. If you choose to perform dynamic changes to the filtering variables, please learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score -1):

In page1.php use:

```
$id=1;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pages where id=$id";
$results = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0)
 {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($results);
        $id = $row["id"];
        $pname = $row["pname"];
        $pimg = $row["pimg"];
        $pstream = $row["pstream"];

}
```

and for page2.php set id to 2 and so on
if you insist to use your method then try

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM pages ORDER BY id ASC";
    $results = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
    $idToShow=1;
    $i=1;
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) 
   {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
       {
           if($id==$idToShow)
         {
            $id = $row["id"];
            $pname = $row["pname"];
            $pimg = $row["pimg"];
            $pstream = $row["pstream"];
         }
         $i++;
       }
    }
```

Like previous make $idToShow=2 for page 2nd and so on

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer and your time writing this. but @Jay has answerd this. thanks again Suzan

Comment: I'm sorry for mistake,it's my fault